# Object Reference Not Set To Instance Of Object When Using InputField Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, reference

I just started learning how to do basic things in Unity. I am trying to learn how to use a text field box. I have followed several tutorials and copied everything but I always end up running into one of two problems. First I get the error stating that the object reference is not set to an instance of an object. Or second, I am unable to assign a text field object in the script inspector. When setting up my project I did the following:

1. Created a new canvas.
2. Added an `InputField` object.
3. Added a `Button.`
4. Created a new script with the following code (this is what I have no but I have tried many variations including using the `[SerializeField]` or changing the `GameObject` to `InputField`):

   ```
   using UnityEngine; using System.Collections; using UnityEngine.UI;

   public class UserInput : MonoBehaviour {
       public GameObject inputField;
       public string msg;

       public void GetInput (){
           msg = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Created empty `GameObject.`
6. Attached the script to the `GameObject.`
7. Edited the button to call the `GetInput` method.
8. Added the `InputField` object to the `Input Field` component in the `GameObject` inspector window. I have also tried adding the `Text object` from the `InputField` (not sure if I am using the correct terminology for everything)

[Note on the right hand side in the inspector I have tried both InputField and Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6RTO.png)
[Call the GetInput method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqzFN.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Component you're trying to access on the 'InputField (TMP)' GameObject is actually a `TMP_InputField` Class, not `Text`, so just change:

```cs
public void GetInput (){
        msg = inputField.GetComponent<Text>().text;
    }
```

to:

```cs
public void GetInput (){
        msg = inputField.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
    }
```

Just tested with the same hierarchy and that solves the issue apparently, msg's value becomes equal to the value of .text .

Just in case, if you attempt to do the same from the GameObject 'Placeholder' or 'Text', notice that they use a different Component, 'TextMeshPro - Text (UI)', in such case you'd use:

```cs
public void GetInput (){
        msg = inputField.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text;
    }
```

Always pay attention to the attached components, there's a "(?)" symbol next to their names in Unity, that will take you to the corresponding page within  Unity3D Docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to solve this for hours.

Comment: You should have a look at [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) this woud have helped you find it quickly.

Comment: in general `TMP_InputField` already has a property [`text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_text) you should stick to ... unless you really really need the `TMP_Text` component attached to it (never go through this unless you really know what you are doing) which it also has a property for [`textComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_InputField.html#TMPro_TMP_InputField_textComponent) => rather use `public TMP_InputField inputField;` and `msg = inputField.text;`